# How to use Oracle regular expression in Java or how to map them?

Tags: java, regex, oracle

How can I use Oracle regular expressions in Java to get the same result or how can I build Java regular expression based on Oracle regular expression.

Oracle:

```
declare
  str1 varchar2(50);
begin
  str1 := REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA', ',[^,]+,');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(str1);
end;
```

Result:

```
, Redwood Shores,
```

Java:

```
String str1 = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",[^,]+,");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA");
if (matcher.find())
{
    str1 = matcher.group(1);
}
```

But this regular expression doesn't work in Java. It fails with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:538)
at mousemover.Playground.main(Playground.java:16)
```

Maybe there is some algorithm to map regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Matcher.group()` or `Matcher.group(0)` to find the match. Calling for group 1 will not work as you do not specify a so-called capturing group in your regex.

From the [Javadoc of Matcher.group(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`.

Comment: thank you. But it doesn't solve the problem with the following regular expression: 'http://([[:alnum:]]+\.?){3,4}/?'

Comment: @Evgenia In this case, it is a different problem. Your using a character class `[[:alnum]]`, which has to be used like this in Java `\p{Alnum}`. Furthermore, this regex contains a capturing group (marked by parantheses), which might require using `group(1)` in the end. Or maybe you can turn it into a non-capturing group. I recommend reading the documentation of `Pattern` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and asking a separate question for this.

Comment: @Evgenia Maybe this helps: `"http://(\\p{Alnum}+\\.\\p{Alnum}{3,4})/?"`. When you apply this to `"http://oracle.com/test"`, `group(1)` wil be `oracle.com`.

Comment: Yes, it helped in this particular case. As I understand each regular expression requires a separate approach and there is no any universal solution?

Comment: Well, depends on how different the things you want to find are. If you can list the rules by which to find the matches in any string, you can make a regex that does it all. But there are some people here with really extensive knowledge about regexes. You should ask a new question when you can express the rules you need.